# Not Showing API weather data in the Tableview

Tags: swift

I am new to IOS coding tried to fetch api weather data and show it in tableview , got the data but unable to show it in Tableview. Could anyone help me on this issue.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource , CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableview : UITableView!
    
    var models = [Name]()
    
    let  locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var currentLocation : CLLocation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableview.register(TodayTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: TodayTableViewCell.identifier)
        tableview.register(WeatherlyTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: WeatherlyTableViewCell.identifier)
        
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource  = self
        location()
        requestforuUpdatingLocation()
        
    }
    
    func location() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if !locations.isEmpty , currentLocation == nil {
            currentLocation = locations.first
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            
        }
    }
    
    func requestforuUpdatingLocation() {
        
        let urlstring = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=0&lon=0&appid=2553332c1366762c77891d87b04c4325"
        let url = URL(string: urlstring)!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
            guard let data=data , error == nil  else{return}
            do {
                let welcome = try JSONDecoder().decode(Name.self, from: data)
                print(welcome)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }
                
            }catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].cod
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Put some `print` statements throughout your code and you will understand. It does not run in the order you think it does...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are not assigning `DataSource` to your `tableview`.

First you need to replace

```
var models = [Name]()
```

with

```
var models: Name?
```

then once you got the data in from server you need to assign that data to your `models` i.e,

```
self.models = try JSONDecoder().decode(Name.self, from: data)
```

And you didn't mentioned your `Name` Codable here you can refer below code for that:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Name
struct Name: Codable {
    let cod: String
    let message, cnt: Int
    let list: [List]
    let city: City
}

// MARK: - City
struct City: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let coord: Coord
    let country: String
    let population, timezone, sunrise, sunset: Int
}

// MARK: - Coord
struct Coord: Codable {
}

// MARK: - List
struct List: Codable {
    let dt: Int
    let main: MainClass
    let weather: [Weather]
    let clouds: Clouds
    let wind: Wind
    let visibility: Int
    let pop: Double
    let sys: Sys
    let dtTxt: String
    let rain: Rain?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dt, main, weather, clouds, wind, visibility, pop, sys
        case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
        case rain
    }
}

// MARK: - Clouds
struct Clouds: Codable {
    let all: Int
}

// MARK: - MainClass
struct MainClass: Codable {
    let temp, feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double
    let pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity: Int
    let tempKf: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp
        case feelsLike = "feels_like"
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
        case pressure
        case seaLevel = "sea_level"
        case grndLevel = "grnd_level"
        case humidity
        case tempKf = "temp_kf"
    }
}

// MARK: - Rain
struct Rain: Codable {
    let the3H: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the3H = "3h"
    }
}

// MARK: - Sys
struct Sys: Codable {
    let pod: Pod
}

enum Pod: String, Codable {
    case d = "d"
    case n = "n"
}

// MARK: - Weather
struct Weather: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main: MainEnum
    let weatherDescription: Description
    let icon: Icon

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, main
        case weatherDescription = "description"
        case icon
    }
}

enum Icon: String, Codable {
    case the03D = "03d"
    case the04D = "04d"
    case the04N = "04n"
    case the10D = "10d"
    case the10N = "10n"
}

enum MainEnum: String, Codable {
    case clouds = "Clouds"
    case rain = "Rain"
}

enum Description: String, Codable {
    case brokenClouds = "broken clouds"
    case lightRain = "light rain"
    case moderateRain = "moderate rain"
    case overcastClouds = "overcast clouds"
    case scatteredClouds = "scattered clouds"
}

// MARK: - Wind
struct Wind: Codable {
    let speed: Double
    let deg: Int
}
```

You can create this kind for `Codable` from `JSON` very easily with the help of

https://app.quicktype.io

And your `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` methods will look like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models?.list.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.models?.list[indexPath.row].dtTxt ?? ""
    return cell
}
```

And your updated code will be:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableview : UITableView!
    
    var models: Name?
    
    let  locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var currentLocation : CLLocation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        tableview.delegate = self
        tableview.dataSource  = self
        location()
        requestforuUpdatingLocation()
        
    }
    
    func location() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if !locations.isEmpty , currentLocation == nil {
            currentLocation = locations.first
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            
        }
    }
    
    func requestforuUpdatingLocation() {
        
        let urlstring = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=0&lon=0&appid=2553332c1366762c77891d87b04c4325"
        let url = URL(string: urlstring)!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            
            guard let data=data , error == nil  else{return}
            do {
                self.models = try JSONDecoder().decode(Name.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }
                
            }catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models?.list.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.models?.list[indexPath.row].dtTxt ?? ""
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it working but getting some error

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added values to your model's object. When weather API is returning data, parse that data and save parsed data into the model's object.

You are using a model object to populate data in the table view.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    return models.count 
}
```

Please update the following function to achieve your desired result.

```
func requestforuUpdatingLocation() {
 let urlstring = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast? 
    lat=0&lon=0&appid=2553332c1366762c77891d87b04c4325"
let url = URL(string: urlstring)!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    
    guard let data=data , error == nil  else{return}
    do {
        let welcome = try JSONDecoder().decode(Name.self, from: data)
        print(welcome)
        model = welcome
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
        
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}.resume() }
```

In the above code snippet `model = welcome` is a game changer.